# How do I store a camera visibility value into a user variable for Renderman in Katana?

Tags: lua, katana, renderman

I have this short piece of code that modifies the attribute that I want. I can modify it but what I really want is to read it and save it into a user variable so that I can evaluate whether the visibility is 'on' or 'off'.

```
Interface.SetAttr("prmanStatements.attributes.visibility.camera", IntAttribute(0))
```

As it stands, that line of code turns off the camera visibility. But when trying to read the value of the same parameter, the result is nil.

```
local currentCamVis = Interface.GetOpArg("prmanStatements.attributes.visibility.camera")
```

Any ideas? clues? suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Why would the setter return something?

Comment: @Luke100000 Yeah you are right, I wrote it in that way to show what I want to do and what I have in a single line of code, I have edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: Alright. Sadly I have no experience here but here some guesses from my side: You use `GetOpArg`, but don't you want to get an attribute instead? Also, [the doc mentiones this](https://learn.foundry.com/katana/dev-guide/OpsAndOpScript/CookInterface/OpScript.html) "Calls to SetAttr() made in the current Op will not be reflected in subsequent calls to GetAttr()." and then recommends `GetOutputAttr` instead. Maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @Luke100000 While that works, the issue is related more to the way renderman works, not so much to the code. Thanks for having a look, ill be reading the documentation and will answer myself if I find something.